# how to check the radio button value that stored in sharedpreferences?

Tags: android, radio-button, sharedpreferences

I'm doing quiz based app.

So i have nearly 50 questions and 4 options(radio group) for each question. 
My problem is in shared preferences.

I have stored the users answer in shared perferences and when i goes to next question and comes to pervious question im getting the user answer in shared perferences, but if i goes again to perivious question im not getting that question answer.. For eg) If i answer 9 question and comes to 8 question im getting this answer and again im comes to 7 or 6 or 5 question here im not getting these answers.

What im doing wrong? How to do this?

Thanks in advance....

> ```
>   btn_practicerg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
>     @Override
>     public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId){
>     RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)group. findViewById(checkedId);
>     String temp = radioButton.getText().toString();
> SharedPreferences settings =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
>     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
>     editor.putString("option", temp); // here temp is the value you want to save
>     editor.commit(); 
>          }
>           });
> ```

When click previous btn

> ```
>      ImageView previousbtn1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.prv_btn);
>       previousbtn1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
>     public void onClick(View v){
> SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
> String optionprev = settings.getString("option","");
>        }
>          });
> ```

I try like this..

Comment: i will suggest you to go with sqllite database. its a better solution. see this (http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) for sqllite in android

Comment: I'm using JSON for retrive data from sever database...

Answer (score 0):

because you are saving all the answers in the same shared preferences variable which is `option` , you have to save it with the number of the question Like this:

```
int numberOfQuestion = //your question's number;
String optionNumber = "option"+numberOfQuestion;
```

the `optionNumber` variable has to be like this:

`option1` for question 1

`option2` for question 2

...

`option50` for question 50

Comment: you are saving your answer in the save variable which is 'option', so each time you are write OVER the previous value of `option`